# Don't be so gloomy, Riley is back!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> To my prefix, don't go back and forth,
>
> My suffix means to possess
>
> My infix can mean line or propel,
>
> Together I make a weird face

**What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer should be

> frown
>  possess: own
>  line or propel: row
>  frown is a weird face
>  also fits with the title, frown is a kind of gloomy face

Not sure about the prefix part

> Is it something about fro? Like don't go back and forth, but go to and fro?

Comment: right on the money with this one as well.. good job..